# PostGIS function that updates WKT geometries to geometry type with st_geomfromtext

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I come from the Python world but I need to create a PostgreSQLl function that providing a table will:

1. Find columns that have "_wkt", i.e. "geom_wkt" or "geom2_wkt".
2. Do an update statement and transforms such WKT columns to Geometry Type with ST_GeomFromText.

This would be very simple to do in Python but I am really not confident with SQL functions.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before the update:**

Run

```
SELECT
  pa.attrelid::REGCLASS, pa.attname
FROM
  pg_attribute AS pa
WHERE
  pa.attrelid = '<schema>.<table>'::REGCLASS
  AND
  pa.attnum > 0
  AND
  pa.attname LIKE '%_wkt'
;
```

to find all columns **with suffix `_wkt`** in `<schema>.<table>` (replace in above query with your actual schema and table names - do not remove the `'`!).

**Make sure the returned table and columns are *exactly* those you want to update - no more no less!**

---

If you are certain that no other relations or columns are involved, run

```
DO
$DO$
  DECLARE
    _rnm REGCLASS;
    _cnm TEXT;
    
  BEGIN
    FOR _rnm, _cnm IN (
      SELECT
        pa.attrelid::REGCLASS, pa.attname
      FROM
        pg_attribute AS pa
      WHERE
        pa.attrelid = '<schema>.<table>'::REGCLASS
        AND
        pa.attnum > 0
        AND
        pa.attname LIKE '%_wkt'
    ) LOOP
      EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $FORMAT$
          ALTER TABLE
            %1$I
            ALTER COLUMN
              %2$s TYPE GEOMETRY(<GEOMETRY_TYPE>, <SRID>) USING %2$s::GEOMETRY(<GEOMETRY_TYPE>, <SRID>)     ;
          
          -- OPTIONAL: remove suffix '_wkt' from column name
          ALTER TABLE
            %1$I
            RENAME COLUMN
              %2$s TO %3$s
          ;
          
          -- OPTIONAL: add spatial index
          CREATE INDEX
            ON %1$I
            USING GIST(%3$s)
          ;
        $FORMAT$,
        _rnm, _cnm, REPLACE(_cnm, '_wkt', '') -- remove the REPLACE statement if you do not want any OPTIONAL functionality!
      );
    END LOOP;
  END;
$DO$
;
```

This will

- update the column data type to `GEOMETRY(<GEOMETRY_TYPE>, <SRID>)` and properly registers the column in the system tables (replace `<GEOMETRY_TYPE>` and `<SRID>` accordingly!)
- OPTIONALLY remove the `_wkt` suffix from the column name
- OPTIONALLY create a spatial index on the new `GEOMETRY` column

*If* you chose the index option, run

```
VACUUM ANALYZE <schema>.<table>;
```

on completion.

---

Note that you have to specifically define the `<GEOMETRY_TYPE>` and `<SRID>` - this will be used for *all* updated columns.

If your columns hold different `<GEOMETRY_TYPE>` you will have to either resolve to use the generic `GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, <SRID>)`, or even simply `GEOMETRY` with no `<SRID>` information - which is undesireable - or add a more complex statement to try to infer the `<GEOMETRY_TYPE>` from the column values; add a note if that is the case and I can see if I have the time to add in the logic.